# How can I change the color of the vertical guide line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the Palenight Theme  in VS code, which I want to modify. A vertical guide line appears on the screen according to the indent, and I want the vertical guide line of the indent I selected to change to red. Only when I select the indent. I need to change the palenight.json file, so please let me know which part to modify.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go to your settings.json and paste:

```
"editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
```

Do not forget to paste it inside

```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
        // "editorIndentGuide.background": "#ff00ff"
    },
```

[image: As you can see, worked for me]

Comment: @andyname Accept my answer, please (tick it)